# На каком ассемблере написан MS-DOS 2.0?

Tags: ассемблер, dos

Недавно нашёл [репозиторий с кодом MS-DOS](https://github.com/microsoft/MS-DOS), хочу собрать из исходников, но так и не смог понять, какой ассемблер используется.

Comment: Ассемблер x86, очевидно... Хотя инструкции там используются даже заведомо ниже уровня i386

Comment: А какой конкретно? TASM, MASM, Nasm и тд

Comment: MASM... там же в README всё написано...

Comment: Большое спасибо незаметил